# Continue .map loop after util.promisify request fails in iteration (async await)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, array.prototype.map

I have the below async function taking in an array of 4 objects. The first one is processed in a .map loop that executes a query and results in an error (in the await executeQuery(queryString)). When this first object is completed processing, the loop ends and the other 3 objects are not processed.

```
async function myFunction(arrayOfObjects, param1) { 

     const promises = arrayOfObjects.map(async function (currElement, i) {
          var queryString = 'www.querystring.com?APIparameter=param1';
          
          const executeQuery = util.promisify(request);

          await executeQuery(queryString).then(data => {

          //process data here using currElement, i
          
          }).catch(err => console.log('error: ', err));   
     });

     await Promise.all(promises).catch();
}
```

I originally only had await Promise.all(promises) and thought revising it to await Promise.all(promises).catch(); would do the trick but it is still failing out on the first object iterated.

I was wondering how best to achieve continuing the .map loop after an error hits the catch in the executeQuery.

Please and thank you!

Comment: This is a tricky one that really got me thinking. Can you try if returning the Promise inside the map function helps? (like: `return await executeQuery(queryString)...`? And is the error thrown from the `executeQuery`-Function itself or within the `then` handler?

Comment: `.catch()` is a no-op, you need to actually pass some callback.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Nothing in your code would stop the other requests or prevent their handlers from being called. Can you post your actual code as a [mcve], please?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what's happening with this code but there are a few things I would change. Firstly it's not good practice to use an `await` inside a loop and secondly, your `promises` array is probably not what you expect as the `await` is yielding until each promise is resolved inside the loop. Return the `Promise` from the `map` function to generate an array of `Promises` that will each resolve and process the data in their own time. You can then `await` all the promises and catch any errors using `try/catch`. Something similar to the following should do what you are expecting...

```
async function myFunction(arrayOfObjects, param1) {

    const executeQuery = util.promisify(request); 

    const promises = arrayOfObjects.map((currElement, i) => {

        const queryString = 'www.querystring.com?APIparameter=param1';

        return executeQuery(queryString).then(data => {

             // process data here using currElement, i
        });   
    });

    try {

        await Promise.all(promises);

        // all promises will be resolved here

    } catch (err) {
        console.log('error: ', err);
    }
}
```

Comment: "*it's not good practice to use an await inside a loop*" - absolutely not!